# Convert one line into multiple line in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I would like to write a pig script for below query.

Input is:

```
ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,AAA,aaa,1,2,3,bbb,1,2,3,ccc,1,2,3,BBB,aaa,1,2,3,bbb,1,2,3,ccc,1,2,3
```

Output should be:

```
ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,AAA,aaa,1,2,3
ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,AAA,bbb,1,2,3
ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,AAA,ccc,1,2,3
ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,BBB,aaa,1,2,3
ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,BBB,bbb,1,2,3
ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,BBB,ccc,1,2,3
```

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own custom UDF or try the below approach

**input.txt**

```
ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,AAA,aaa,1,2,3,bbb,1,2,3,ccc,1,2,3,BBB,aaa,1,2,3,bbb,1,2,3,ccc,1,2,3,CCC,aaa,1,2,3,bbb,1,2,3,ccc,1,2,3
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0,$1,$2,$3,
                       FLATTEN(TOTUPLE($4)),
                       FLATTEN(TOBAG(
                                     TOTUPLE($5..$8),
                                     TOTUPLE($9..$12),
                                     TOTUPLE($13..$16)
                                    )
                              );
C = FOREACH A GENERATE $0,$1,$2,$3,
                       FLATTEN(TOTUPLE($17)),
                       FLATTEN(TOBAG(
                                     TOTUPLE($18..$21),
                                     TOTUPLE($22..$25),
                                     TOTUPLE($26..$29)
                                    )
                              );
D = UNION B,C;
DUMP D
```

**Output:**

```
(ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,AAA,aaa,1,2,3)
(ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,AAA,bbb,1,2,3)
(ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,AAA,ccc,1,2,3)
(ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,BBB,aaa,1,2,3)
(ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,BBB,bbb,1,2,3)
(ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,BBB,ccc,1,2,3)
```